# Swift Error type 'usersVC' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I keep on getting a compiling error on my code. I am not sure whats happening. Please help! I have tried looking all over other forums but nothing is helping me. I am using parse for my project if that matters...

```
//
//  usersVC.swift
//  CaastRun
//
//  Created by Computer on 5/23/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Caast. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class usersVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!
    var resultsNameArray = [String]()
    var resultsUserNameArray = [String]()
    var resultsImageFiles = [PFFile]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
        let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

        resultsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableview(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return resultsNameArray.count

    }

    func tableview(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:usersCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! usersCell

        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: Typos: `tableview` should be `tableView` with a capital V. – Voting to close as off-topic because of a simple typographic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Martin R, this section of code needs the 'V' in tableView capitalised:

Change this:

```
   func tableview(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return resultsNameArray.count

    }
```

To this:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return resultsNameArray.count

    }
```

Comment: You **override** the methods only in a subclass of `UITableViewController`, but OP has a subclass of  `UIViewController` ... And those are `UITableViewDataSource` methods, not  `UITableViewDelegate` methods.